# How to get the length of a dynamically created array of structs in C?

Tags: c

I am currently trying to get the length of a dynamically generated array. It is an array of structs:

```
typedef struct _my_data_ 
{
  unsigned int id;
  double latitude;
  double longitude;
  unsigned int content_len;
  char* name_dyn;
  char* descr_dyn;
} mydata;
```

I intialize my array like that:

```
mydata* arr = (mydata*) malloc(sizeof(mydata));
```

And then resized it using **realloc** and started to fill it with data.

I then attempted to get its size using the code described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37538/how-do-i-determine-the-size-of-my-array-in-c).

```
sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0])
```

This operation returns **0** even though my array contains two elements.

Could someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You can't programmatically obtain the size of a dynamically allocated array other than by manually saving the size in a variable, using a sentinel value, etc

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you need to know the size of a dynamically-allocated array, you have to keep track of it yourself.

The `sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0])` technique only works for arrays whose size is known at compile time, and for C99's [variable-length arrays](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array).

Answer (score 5):

`sizeof` cannot be used to find the amount of memory that you allocated dynamically using `malloc`. You should store this number separately, along with the pointer to the allocated chunk of memory. Moreover, you must update this number every time you use `realloc` or `free`.

Comment: +1 for the OP's problem, but this answer's not quite 100% true - you're right for `malloc()`, but C99 variable-length arrays *do* work with `sizeof`.

Comment: @CarlNorum Thanks for the clarification - I updated the answer to mention `malloc` specifically.

Answer (score 3):

```
mydata* arr = (mydata*) malloc(sizeof(mydata));
```

is a `pointer` and not an `array`. To create an `array` of two items of `mydata`, you need to do the following

```
mydata arr[2];
```

Secondly, to allocate two elements of `mydata` using `malloc()`, you need to do the following:

```
mydata* arr = (mydata*) malloc(sizeof(mydata) * 2);
```

OTOH, length for dynamically allocated memory (using `malloc()`) should be maintained by the programmer (in the variables) - `sizeof()` won't be able to track it!

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to use a pretty well known trick to find the number of elements in an array.  Unfortunately `arr` in your example is *not* an array, it's a pointer.  So what you're getting in your `sizeof` division is:

```
sizeof(pointer) / sizeof(structure)
```

Which is probably always going to be 0.