# Size of C Array

Tags: c, arrays

there is a question puzzles me.In the code below msg and quote are both char array.why sizeof(msg) and sizeof(quote) gave me different result?

**Code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>

void fortune_cookie(char msg[])
{
    printf("Message reads: %s\n",msg);
    printf("msg occupies %i bytes\n",sizeof(msg));

}

int main()
{
    char quote[] = "Cookies make you fat";

    printf("quote occupies %i bytes\n",sizeof(quote));

    fortune_cookie(quote);
    return 0;
}
```

**Result:**

```
quote occupies 21 bytes                                                                                                              
Message reads: Cookies make you fat
msg occupies 8 bytes
```

Comment: `void fortune_cookie(char msg[])` is the same as `void fortune_cookie(char* msg)`, so you get sizeof(char*), your result is 8 which means you're using 64-bit machine, right?

Comment: this question has been here many times. Could you please search a bit before asking?

Answer (score 1):

`sizeof` an array equals total of `sizeof` each element.

When you pass an array to a function, it passes the pointer.

In your case:

`quote` occupies 21 bytes: Means your char array has 21 elements and each element size is 1.
`msg` occupies 8 bytes: Means your parameter is a pointer, it will hold 8 bytes on 64-bit machine and 4 bytes on 32-bit machine.

Answer (score 0):

Here     `char quote[] = "Cookies make you fat";`
memory is allocated for the message inside `quote[]` that's why the size of the `quote[]` is 21 bytes.

`void fortune_cookie(char msg[])`  Here `char msg[]` is same as `char *msg` and its a pointer to the `quote`, because you are passing quote to `fortune_cookie(quote);`
Size of pointer is depending on the machine. I think you are using 64 bit machine that's why you are getting 8 as its size.

Answer (score 0):

The `quote` is an array in the scope of the `main` function. The sizeof an array is the number of bytes that it occupies, which is the length of your string + 1 for the null byte at the end.

When you pass it to the `fortune_cookie`, it is demoted to a pointer. The size of a pointer is 4 bytes in 32bit architectures and 8 bytes in 64bit architectures. To see the same output, you can change the signature of the `fortune_cookie`:

```
void fortune_cookie(char msg[21])
```

But that is generally not practical.

Answer (score 0):

Hiiii..

When sizeof() is applied to the name of an array the result will be the size of the whole array in bytes.
Here the **name of an array is converted to a pointer to the first element of the array**.

Now when we pass this array as a Parameter to the function the receiving function variable is just the pointer , which will point the same array, we can not pass an array as Call by Value.

So "**sizeof(msg)**" will always display Size of a pointer.

For refrence see .:http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sizeof
and [Stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8717267/how-to-get-the-length-of-a-dynamically-created-array-of-structs-in-c)

Comment: -1: Why do you say a static array? Also, the call by value comment is irrelevant.

Comment: Its because dynamic array can be resized using realloc. And If i want to get the size I need to track myself about the actual size calculation. For refrence you can c [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sizeof) and [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8717267/how-to-get-the-length-of-a-dynamically-created-array-of-structs-in-c)

Comment: I think the correct term is just array. When you say static it refers to something like `static char array[21]`.

Comment: So please edit your answer such that it becomes correct. Otherwise it might confuse others, later.